# Recycle View in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

My recycle can be scrolled the NestedScrollView. However, it is not smooth as usual. Can anybody please help me to fix this.

Here is my code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/fg_movie_list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: i am thinking why would you need a nested scrollview as a parent of recyclerview

Comment: I am using activity
 with navigation drawer, coordinator layout

Comment: and the fragment contains the recycle view

Comment: still doesn't make sense coz recyclerview is a scrollable view so why you need a nested scrollview as parent

Comment: well as far it is a duplicate so lets close it here ;) have happy coding

Comment: If my answer is useful for you .Could you accept and upvote it ?@AlexCrowel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```